# Оптимизация SQL запроса

Tags: sql, sql-server

Добрый день!

Есть таблица `docs`, в ней хранится данные о документах. Есть таблица `docs_duplicate` в ней храниться данные о дублированных документах и так же `ID` оригинал документа. Мне надо вытащить все записи(документы) с таблицы `docs` исключая дубликаты. Есть запрос который я построил на шару!

```
  select * from docs d
    where d.id not in(select dd.docs_id_parent from docs_duplicate dd)
```

Есть - ли алтернативные(быстрее чем этот) варианты запроса?

Таблица `docs`

```
------------------------------
|id| start_date | end_date   |
------------------------------
|1 | 01-01-2011 | 01-01-2012 | 
------------------------------
|2 | 22-04-2011 | 22-04-2012 | 
------------------------------
|3 | 14-12-2011 | 14-12-2012 | 
------------------------------
|4 | 25-09-2011 | 25-09-2012 | 
------------------------------
|5 | 01-06-2011 | 01-06-2012 | 
------------------------------
|6 | 21-09-2011 | 21-09-2012 | 
------------------------------
```

Таблица `docs_duplicate`

```
---------------------------
|id|docs_id_parent|docs_id|
---------------------------
|1 |      1       | 3     |
---------------------------
|2 |      4       | 5     |
---------------------------
|3 |      3       | 6     |
---------------------------
```

Comment: Я бы добавил в таблицу docs один числовой столбец, который бы указывал в дублирующих документах на оригинал. Тогда, чтобы получить оригиналы хватило бы проверки данного столбца на пустоту.

Comment: @Visman, Хорошая мысль! Но это не по моему случая, я не имею таких прав.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Текст запроса ничего не говорит о том, быстро или медленно он работает. Нельзя глядя на вариант запроса X сказать что он работает быстрее, чем вариант запроста Y.

"Скорость работы" - это минимум 3 раздельных показателя

- нагрузка на CPU
- нагрузка на диск (чтение)
- нагрузка на диск (запись в лог)

SQL Server не выполняет запрос "как написано". Выполнение запроса всегда состоит из

- построения плана - преобразования текста SQL в конкретный механизм выполнения
- выполнения запроса по плану

При этом план запроса для одного и того же текста может выглядеть по разному в зависимости от статистики распределения значений в таблице. И от актуальности этой статистики. И от наличия индексов. И, естественно, от количества значений. И от версии SQL Server. И от edition.

Что делат "оптимизацию запроса по тексту" достаточно странным занятием. Потому что текст вообще ничего не говорит о том, что будет происходить при выполнении.

Например, если данных порядка десятков тысяч строк (т.е. не 2-3 строки, а с более-менее реальными данными) то (на моей машине, на SQL Express, без дополнительных индексов)

- планы запросов с NOT EXISTS и NOT IN совпадают:
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- план запроса с LEFT JOIN выглядят чуть иначе:
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

дисковая статистика (`set statistics io on`) одинакова для всех 4 запросов:

```
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Workfile'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'docs_duplicate'. Scan count 1, logical reads 109, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'docs'. Scan count 1, logical reads 203, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

и при этом все запросы отрабатывают примерно за 500ms (на количестве записей 40/20 тысяч, смотреть стоит с помощью `set statistics time on` c **отключенным** actual execution plan)

Что можно ускорить:

В плане видны clustered index scan-ы по таблице `docs_duplicate`. Это, практически, пробег по всем записям с построением списка `doc_id_parent` / `doc_id` для последующей фильтрации. Hash match / aggregate с последующей сортировкой (она ест CPU!) - это построение уникального списка из здоровой выборки на 20к записей. Можно построить эти списки заранее:

```sql
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_docs_duplicate_doc_id ON [dbo].[docs_duplicate]
(
    [docs_id] ASC
)

-- для других вариантов
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_docs_duplicate_doc_parent_id ON [dbo].[docs_duplicate]
(
    [docs_id_parent] ASC
)
```

Это поменяет планы на примерно такие:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И статистику по io (на моих данных!) на

```
Table 'docs_duplicate'. Scan count 1, logical reads 45, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'docs'. Scan count 1, logical reads 203, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

Обращений к docs_duplicate стало меньше. В зависимости от данных в таблице - их может быть намного меньше. 
И срежет время выполнения (у меня - с 450-500ms до 350-450ms)

Почему это происходит:

- SQL Server-у больше не приходится сканнировать таблицу и искать уникальные значения. Т.е. ему не надо тратить время процессора на хэширование и сортировку (в первом плане). Он просто берет данные из индекса и льет их наверх.
- Данные в новых индексах отсортированы. Два отсортированных потока данных можно сждойнить слиянием, а не через hash join. Это тоже снимает нагрузку с CPU.
- Больше не используются временные таблицы (worktable/workfile). На оригинальных планах этого не видно, но любая hash/sort операция требует памяти. Если SQL Server не угадает с объемом сортировки (из-за старой статистики или из-за положения луны) и выделит слишком мало памяти - он обнаружит это уже в процессе джойна/сортировки. И сделает то, что назывется spill to tempdb - начнет сортировать данные не в памяти, а на диске. SELECT, пишущий на диск - это обычно довольно неприятный сюрприз - даже если у вас SSD.

TL;DR - ВСЕГДА обновляйте статистику перед попытками оптимизировать запрос. Не создавайте индексы наугад. Смотрите планы, а не текст запроса. Оптимизируйте проблемы в плане, а не в тексте. Не верьте в лечение по фотографии.

Comment: Благодарю за ваш глубокий ответ на вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Обратите внимание, что в этом запросе соединение осуществляется по `dd.docs_id`. Это позволяет отсечь из таблицы `docs` документы, которые указаны как дубликаты в таблице `docs_duplicate`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM docs d
LEFT JOIN docs_duplicate dd ON d.id = dd.docs_id 
WHERE dd.docs_id IS NULL
```

Неверно делать соединение по `dd.docs_id_parent`, так как результат будет другой. Выборка будет содержать документы, у которых нет дубликатов и этими документами могут быть и сами дубликаты.

Comment: согласен. эту логику должен выбрать сам автор вопроса. так как когда давал ответ структура таблицы не было и поле `docs_id` тоже

Comment: И на самом деле вы правы, ваш запрос вывел мне на 4 строки меньше строк, но длиться так же.  Буду считать ваш запрос приоритетным. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @ШыназАлиш А у вас есть индекс по полю docs_id в таблице docs_duplicate? Если его нет, то добавьте и посмотрите результат. Какой количество строк в ваших таблицах?

Comment: @BOPOH нет! 3 это сслыка на дубликат в docs. Его выводить не нужно. А 1 - это оригинал. Задача вывести документы, которые не являются дубликатами!

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте это

```
SELECT * 
FROM docs d
LEFT JOIN docs_duplicate dd ON d.id = dd.docs_id_parent
WHERE dd.docs_id_parent IS NULL
```

Comment: OUTER JOIN не существует. Возможно вы имели ввиду LEFT JOIN (или LEFT OUTER JOIN).

Comment: спасибо, не заметил.

Comment: @SaidolimDjuraev, Спасибо за ваш ответ. Он быстрее чем мой запрос на 1 секунду. Пока буду считать правильным ваш ответ! Если до завтра не найдеться лучше(быстрее) ответ, тогда помечу ваш ответ как ОТВЕТ на вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Иногда not exist дает очень неплохие результаты

```
SELECT *
FROM docs d
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM docs_duplicate dd
                  WHERE d.id = dd.docs_id)
```